# Multi-part identifier error showing while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
 @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
  @enddate NVARCHAR(100)AS BEGINDECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @cols = STUFF((  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
  FROM dbo.VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
 SET @query =
    'SELECT  LocName,Date, ' + @cols + '
     from  ( 
            select  l.LocName,v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
            from Transaction_tbl t 
            join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + ''' 
                and locid IN (SELECT l.Locid FROM dbo.Location_tbl l)
    ) d pivot ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
END
```

while execution I am getting error like this:

> The multi-part identifier "l.LocName" could not be bound.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the locname, instead of using the subquery, use the table name in a join. Here is the sample:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
 @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
  @enddate NVARCHAR(100)AS BEGINDECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @cols = STUFF((  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
  FROM dbo.VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
 SET @query =
    'SELECT  LocName,Date, ' + @cols + '
     from  ( 
            select  l.LocName,v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
            from Transaction_tbl t 
            join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
            join dbo.Location_tbl l on t.locid=l.Locid
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + ''' 
                    ) d pivot ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
END
```

Here I've removed the subquery and joined the Location_tbl with the Transaction_tbl on LocId column.

Comment: sir i want to get locname in ascending order.so where i have to give order by

Comment: i given like this:where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + enddate + ''' orderby l.LocName but getting error:The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Your outer query is not selecting anything from the `l`L table. You're only using that in the `and locid IN (...)` subquery. You cannot use ANY fields from that subquery in the parent query, EXCEPT for the one `l.locid` field, and only within the `IN (...)` comparison.

Comment: sir,,how i can re-write this query